# handling of floating points in rcpp: a value of -0 in R becomes 0 in C++ using Rcpp

Tags: c++, r, floating-point, rcpp

A parameter with value of -0 in R becomes 0 in C++ world when using Rcpp. Here is a minimal example that demonstrates this.

```
library("Rcpp")
cppFunction(' 
 void signCheck(NumericVector v ) {
   int vint = Rcpp::as<int>(v);
   if (vint < 0) {
      Rcout << "    v is negative";
   }
   else if (vint == 0) {
      Rcout << "v is zero";
   }
   else {
      Rcout << "v is positive";
   }

 }
')



a = -0
print(paste("sign in R", sign(1/a)))
signCheck(a)
```

Here is the output:

```
[1] "sign in R -1"
v is zero
```

In short, The difference in -0 and 0 vanishes. Is this a bug? Is there any work around?

Comment: FYI on this section http://adv-r.had.co.nz/Rcpp.html#rcpp-intro which has a sign function. Also, why `sign(1/a)` and not `sign(a)` ?

Comment: And apart from @Konrad's answer you have to think through:  what influence could or would `Rcpp` have here?  This is a language standard and compiler issue.

Comment: @M.Viking Because `sign(-0)` is 0, not -1.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is no bug. The behaviour is as expected: the `int` type in C++ (or virtually anywhere else) has no negative zero representation. The distinction between +0 and −0 only exists in IEEE floating point types. The number literal you have in R is a floating point number (to get an integral type, use the `L` suffix: `0L`). But your C++ code intentionally converts it to `int` and therefore coerces it to 0, dropping the sign information.

Furthermore, your C++ code does not actually check for the sign of the value: the same code in R would also output “v is zero” rather than “v is negative”:

```r
a = -0
if (a < 0) "negative" else if (a == 0) "zero" else "positive"
# [1] "zero"
```

By contrast, we can verify that C++ *does* in fact preserve signed 0:

```r
Rcpp::cppFunction("
  void signCheck(NumericVector v) {
    Rcout << std::signbit(v[0]);
  }
")
signCheck(-0)
# 1
```

(`std::signbit` returns `true` for negative numbers, which is indicated here by the output `1`.)

Comment: Re “in C++ (or elsewhere)”: Really? Nowhere else on the planet, at all? Does somebody not have a one’s complement C implementation running in a computing history museum?

Comment: @EricPostpischil I make no claim of exclusivity. I am sure somebody somewhere defined an integral type that has signed 0. Maybe they even called that type `int`. Has it got any practical relevance? No.

Comment: So the “or elsewhere” is incorrect.

Comment: @EricPostpischil Is it? I didn't write “or *anywhere* else”, which would be distinct (and likely wrong). It was a conscious choice to use the less well-defined “elsewhere” instead, *precisely* so that I could avoid having to include a tortuous disclaimer that would distract from the main point. Well, now that tortuous disclaimer is in the comments.

Comment: Programmers, English professors, and Lawyers. Probably the only people who would write tortuous rather than torturous,